# adding label from label data frame on facet chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot

```
dat = data.frame(group = c("A","A","B","B"), pct = c(.2,.3,.5,.4), subgroup = c("D","E","D","E"), x = c("Z","Z","Z","Z"))


ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = factor(x), y  =pct, fill= subgroup ))+geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")+facet_wrap(~group)
```

And I want to add a label above each stacked Z that is the sum of the 2 components so I build a lable data frame and use geom_text:

```
LABEL = data.frame(x = c("Z","Z"),  y = c(.5,.9), group = c("A","B"))
    ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = factor(x), y  =pct, fill= subgroup ))+geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")+facet_wrap(~group)+geom_text(aes(x= x,y=y ,label=labs), data = LABEL, vjust=-.2, size = 3)
```

but because subgroup is not in the dataframe I get an error

```
 : object 'subgroup' not found
```

but I DO NOT want subgroup in the data frame as the label I am plotting is for the sum of each of the subgroups.

The example above has one stacked bar per facet but the solutions should work for any number of stacked bars per facet plot.

Comment: Try `inherit.aes = FALSE` in `geom_text`.  Or remove `fill` from the global `ggplot`.

Comment: That does not seem to work. Is it working for you can you post the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
dat = data.frame(group = c("A","A","B","B"), 
                 pct = c(.2,.3,.5,.4), 
                 subgroup = c("D","E","D","E"), 
                 x = c("Z","Z","Z","Z"))

LABEL = data.frame(x = c("Z","Z"),  
                   y = c(.5,.9), 
                   group = c("A","B"))

ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = factor(x), y  =pct)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill= subgroup), position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~group) +
    geom_text(aes(x= x,y=y ,label=y), data = LABEL, vjust=-.2, size = 3)
```